Mein Token (Unicorn Gold Dust) ist verschwunden aus meiner Wallet (Phantom)
Eventuell kann mir jemand helfen ob ich Opfer eines Angriffes geworden bin oder sonstiges. Auf einmal ohne das ich etwas versendet habe sind meine Token weg. eventuell kann mir jemand sagen was passiert ist? Es waren immerhin 100$…
Solana Adresse:
29vidmWrweN8JrkgpEzKUNZ2bZgDWMWARk1htTZx7pfR
Coin: UGD 100$

I’m voting to close this question because questions on the Solana Stack Exchange must be written in English and be about Solana development.
